# Multiple DataFields in Asp CheckBoxList?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'm currently working on a small quiz type app that populates questions and answers from an SQL .mdf database. I've been looking for a control in Visual Studio 2012 that could hold the four answers (preferably `checkboxlist`).

The only problem is I have the questions saved in different columns, `answer1`, `answer2` etc.

The main question is, **is there a way to populate the `checkboxlist` control with multiple data fields rather than just one?**

I tried using four separate `checkboxlists`, but this made validation extremely difficult (Only one option should be selected). Does anyone have any advice or suggest how I could insert the four columns into a control that I could validate?

I read online about combining the answers using sql ie. `SELECT Answer1 + ' ' + Answer2`, this works but again I don't know how to integrate this into a combo box list.

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: Check out SQL Server unpivot syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two easy ways:

on the database side you could use:

```
SELECT convert(Char,[Answer1]) FROM [TABLE1] union ALL  SELECT convert(char,[Answer2])   FROM [TABLE1]
```

From the application side you could use Merge:

```
 dim dt as new datatable
dt = SQLdataTable("SELECT [Answer1]  FROM [TABLE1]")
dt.Merge(SQLdataTable("SELECT [Answer2]  FROM [TABLE1]").Copy)
```